# Does Ubuntu install drivers for Intel graphics and Nvidia cards?

Tags: system-installation

When I install Ubuntu for the first time, does the installation procedure get drivers for the Intel graphics built in to the system, as well as the Nvidia card, which is what I wish to use?

Comment: Note: If this is a laptop with "Optimus" dynamic graphics card switching, this feature is not yet available in Ubuntu. Search for Optimus and Bubmlebee in this site and see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee.

Answer (score 1):

**Intel** drivers come by default, if I remember correctly.

**Nvidia** drivers, you will have to install the via the "additional drivers program". It should prompt you at some point after the install though. Once you install them, you just restart.